# Drupal 8 Change menu link based on current route

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-views, drupal-8, drupal-contextual-filters

I have a Drupal 8 page views with contextual filter, and path of the same is like:

```
/category/%cid/product/%pid
```

Here %cid and %pid are contextual filters of the page view.

In this page, I want to change my footer menu, to alter the links so that:

```
/privacy-policy
```

becomes

```
/productname/privacy-policy
```

only if any node created and it has url path settings:

```
/productname/privacy-policy
```

How to achieve this.

Note:
based on the discussion in [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/2118147) I tried,

- To alter routes, implement a RouteSubscriber
- To alter menu links, use hook_menu_links_discovered_alter()

I can not achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to achieve similar thing by using hook_menu_links_discovered_alter() and it generally works:

```
  function mymodule_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links) {
      $links['linkid']['title'] = 'Some new title';
      $links['linkid']['url'] = 'http://www.google.com';
    }
```

link title and url is changed. But problem I'm facing is that those changes are heavily cached. I.e. if I set title depending on current language title will be correct for the first visit but that title will be remembered and used for each visit after that. So when I switch language title will remain the same (cached one).

Comment: Check also my other solution (without caching problem) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254659/drupal-8-how-to-create-multi-lingual-menu-item-from-links-menu-yml/52277756#52277756