# Drupal 8: How to create multi lingual menu item from .links.menu.yml

Tags: menu, translation, drupal-8

So, at many places, i.e. here:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-menu-links

It's explained how to add menu item to some existing menu from `module_name.links.menu.yml` of your module.

Problem is that menu items can be translatable (from back-end), but I didn't find anywhere how to add menu items in multiple languages? Is that possible at all?

So, I have one menu, I want to add one menu item, but on each language that menu item should have different title and different url where it leads to.

Answer (score 1):

Succeeded. First links.menu.yml I created like this:

```
my_menu_item_id:
  title: 'Dummy Title'
  description: 'Dummy Description'
  url: http://www.google.com
  parent: mainmenu
  menu_name: mainmenu
  weight: -100
```

Then I added to my module `hook_menu_links_discovered_alter()` like this:

```
   function mymodule_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links) {
          $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
          $links['my_menu_item_id']['title'] = 'Title:'.$language;
   }
```

And basically that works, but problem is that it's not executed with every request, but it's cached. So i.e. if you want to have different title or url depending on language it won't work. Version for first language will be cached and for all other languages same cached version will be used.
So I had to go for different solution:

Instead of using that hook function I added "class" parameter to links.menu.yml:

```
my_menu_item_id:
  class: Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Menu\MyPluginClass
  title: 'Dummy Title'
  description: 'Dummy Description'
  url: http://www.google.com
  parent: mainmenu
  menu_name: mainmenu
  weight: -100
```

Then of course, I created that class in `my_module/src/Plugin/Menu` (don't forget to put plugin inside src dir!) and it looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Menu;

use Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkDefault;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

    class MyPluginClass extends MenuLinkDefault {


      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      public function getTitle() {

        $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

        return (string) 'Title: '.$language;
      }

      public function getUrlObject($title_attribute = TRUE) {
        return Url::fromUri('http://www.yahoo.com');
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Menu title translation is available out of the box!**

The english title set in `links.menu.yml` is passed through Drupal's interface translation when the menu tree is built (rendered), so either you provide translations with your module using `.po` files, or you just manually translate the title at `/admin/config/regional/translate`.